# How to select more that one element in jquery to avoid code duplication?

Tags: jquery

I've just added functionality to allow users to upload and track files. So far, I was working on page and it's working perfectly. Now, I've noticed that, even tough pages looks the same, but in reality there are aspx and cshtml pages. So, why the links show "Upload Files", in the HTML could look like:

- `<a id="Repeater1_menuLinkButton_7" class="ui-state-default xci-button" role="button" aria-disabled="false">Upload Files</a>`
- `<a href="#" class="ui-state-mainNav ui-state-default xci-button" role="button" aria-disabled="false">Upload Files</a>`
- Possibly other type of ids

Before realizing that there was not only one type, this is how I was selecting reacting to the click of the link:

```
$('#Repeater1_menuLinkButton_7').click(function () {
     //code here ...
 });
```

With the second a element without ID, it would be something like:

```
$("a:contains('Upload Files')").click(function () {
     //code here ...
 });
```

Is there a way to select more than one element to avoid code duplication?

Thank for helping.

Comment: You can separate selectors by `,` https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

Comment: Why don't you just add a custom class (e.x. file-upload) to all links with the same functionality use it as selector? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a different CSS selector, in this case adding [`,`](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/):

```
$("#Repeater1_menuLinkButton_7,a:contains('Upload Files')").click(function () {
     //code here ...
});
```

Or use jQuery's [`.add()`](https://api.jquery.com/add/) method:

```
$('#Repeater1_menuLinkButton_7').add("a:contains('Upload Files')").click(function () {
     //code here ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

### HTML ##

```
   <input type="button" id="button1" value="Button1" />
    <input type="button" id="button2" value="Button2" />
    <input type="button" id="button3" value="Button3" />
    <input type="button" id="button4" value="Button4" />
```

### Jquery

```
 $('#button1, #button2, #button3, #button4').click(function(event){



         if($(event.target).attr('id')=='button1'){
            /* File upload code for upload1 */
             alert("Button 1 Clicked");
        } else if($(event.target).attr('id')=='button2'){
            /* File upload code for upload2 */
               alert("Button 2 Clicked");
        } else if($(event.target).attr('id')=='button3'){
            /* File upload code for upload3 */
            alert("Button 3 Clicked");
        } else if($(event.target).attr('id')=='button4'){
            /* File upload code for upload4 */
             alert("Button 4 Clicked");
        } 

    })
```

[Demo Check this out Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yw67z3j1/)

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options:

Option 1 - Define your function outside of the event handling assignment, and pass it in as an argument

```
function myFunction() {
     // Do some stuff
}
// note the lack of parentheses when passing the function
$('#Repeater1_menuLinkButton_7').click(myFunction);
$("a:contains('Upload Files')").click(myFunction);
```

Option 2 - select both elements at the same time, separating by a comma

```
$("#Repeater1_menuLinkButton_7, a:contains('Upload Files')").click(function () {
    // Do some stuff
});
```

Option 3 - add a new class to all elements that you want to assign to

```
$(".myNewClass").click(function () {
    // Do some stuff
});
```